# Google Appengine, NDB: Suppress tasklet warnings

Tags: python, google-app-engine

just a minor annoyance, but it seems AppEngine's NDB (Python) is generating warnings for errors originating from models, whether the exception is handled or not:

```
testCannotInsertWithoutCurrency (expense_test.ExpenseTest) ... {'amount': 9.9, 'description': 'Foo'}
WARNING:root:initial generator _put_tasklet(context.py:335) raised BadValueError(Entity has uninitialized properties: currency)
WARNING:root:suspended generator put(context.py:812) raised BadValueError(Entity has uninitialized properties: currency)
```

As you see from the output, I'm just writing tests, so I'm actually expecting the Error to happen and I'm not interested in all the noise generated by the warnings. Is there any way to disable this? Can't find anything in the docs regarding to log level, etc.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting your log levels.

Comment: I tried to find out how to do just that and I didn't find anything.

Comment: Umm - the same way you always do with logging - 
`logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)`  You may find there is explicit logging set in module the tasklet code comes from though.

Comment: would you mind writing the last comment as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly set the log level using setLevel method of a logger.

e.g.

```
 logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Comment: Works as advertised - setting level to logging.ERROR mutes the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to set the blanket log level, you can also use `ndb.add_flow_exception(BadValueError)` within a tasklet to inform the tasklet that a specific exception is expected, and it should not warn for it.

`BadValueError` should be the exception you expect.

See the first item at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/functions